# error java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0 java JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tengo un código para inicio de sesión el que no me direcciona a las a la carpeta y página xhtml. me muestra el error.

```
08:31:12,556 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.context] (default task-1) java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.faces.component.AttachedObjectListHolder.restoreState(AttachedObjectListHolder.java:146)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.restoreState(UIComponentBase.java:1228)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy$2.visit(FaceletPartialStateManagementStrategy.java:372)
```

Esto sucede cuando presiono por segunda ocación el boton iniciar sesión a la primera no ejecuta nada. 
En mi ingreso.xhtml tengo el siguiente formulario

```
<h:form>
            <div class="ui-g-12" style="padding-top: 35px;">
                <p:inputText placeholder="Ingrese el Nickname" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Debe Ingresar su Nickname" 
                     value="#{beanLogin.nickname}"
                    style="width:60%;">
                    <p:ajax update="@form" oncomplete="#{beanLogin.onChange()}"/>
                    </p:inputText>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-12" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <p:password placeholder="Contraseña" required="true"
                    requiredMessage="Ingrese su contraseña" value="#{beanLogin.clave}"
                    inline="true" style="width:60%" />
            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-12" style="padding-top: 10px;">
                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{beanLogin.rol}"
                    placeholder="Rol de Usuario" style="width:60%">
                    <f:selectItems value="#{beanLogin.cr}" var="c"
                        itemLabel="#{c.tipoRol}" itemValue="#{c.idRol}" />
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </div>

                    <div class="ui-g-12">
                <p:commandButton value="Iniciar Sesión" 
                    action="#{beanLogin.actionLogin()}"></p:commandButton>
            </div>
        </h:form>
```

el método que utilizo de action login es el siguiente.

```
public void onChange() {
    cr = ma.searchRol(nickname);
}

public String actionLogin() {
    try {
        int rolUser = ma.findIdRolByUser(nickname, rol);
        loginConfirm = ma.comprobarUsuario(nickname, clave);
        Mensajes.crearMensajeInfo("Login Correcto");
        if (rolUser == 1) {
            return "Finanzas/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 2) {
            return "Bodega/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 3) {
            return "AdminContratos/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 4) {
            return "Solicitante/dashboard";
        }
        if (rolUser == 5) {
            return "Contabilidad/dashboard";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Mensajes.crearMensajeError(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

y el codigo en mi manager es:

```
public List<UsuarioRol> searchRolUs(String nickname, int idRol) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UsuarioRol u WHERE u.catUsuario.nickname =:nickname"
            + " AND u.catRole.idRol =:idRol");
    q.setParameter("nickname", nickname);
    q.setParameter("idRol", idRol);
    return q.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
}

public int findIdRolByUser(String nickname, int idRol) {
    int res = 0;
        List<UsuarioRol> r = searchRolUs(nickname, idRol);
        for (UsuarioRol user : r) {
            res = user.getCatRole().getIdRol();
            break;
        }
    return res;
}
```

public List searchUsuario(String nickname) {
        Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UsuarioRol u WHERE u.catUsuario.nickname=:nickname");
        q.setParameter("nickname", nickname);
        return q.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();
    }

```
public boolean comprobarUsuario(String nickname, String clave) throws Exception {
    List<UsuarioRol> u = searchUsuario(nickname);
    CatUsuario usuario = new CatUsuario();
    for (UsuarioRol user : u) {
        usuario.setNickname(user.getCatUsuario().getNickname());
        usuario.setClaveUs(user.getCatUsuario().getClaveUs());
        break;
    }
    if (usuario.getNickname() == null)
        throw new Exception("El usuario " + nickname + " no existe");
    if (usuario.getClaveUs().equals(clave)) 
        return true;
    throw new Exception("La clave que ingreso es incorrecta");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despues de rehacer el código con las recomendaciones, el error se he encontrado en el bean al no implementar una redirección como la siguiente:

```
return "Solicitante/dashboard?faces-redirect=true";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hola IndexOutOfBoundsException es una subclase de RuntimeException, lo que significa que es una excepción no verificada que se genera para indicar que un índice de algún tipo (como una matriz, una cadena o un vector) está fuera de rango, por ejemplo, usando List.

este error sirve para indicar que se ha accedido a una matriz con un índice ilegal. El índice es negativo o mayor o igual que el tamaño de la matriz o lista.

puede que el error se de en el siguiente código, cuando la consulta no devuelva ninguna valor.

return q.setMaxResults(1).getResultList();

porque usas una lista si solo necesitas un solo objeto, te recomiendo validar si la lista trae algo, lo puedes hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
public UsuarioRol searchRolUs(String nickname, int idRol) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM UsuarioRol u WHERE u.catUsuario.nickname =:nickname"
            + " AND u.catRole.idRol =:idRol");
    q.setParameter("nickname", nickname);
    q.setParameter("idRol", idRol);
   List<UsuarioRol> resultList = query.getResultList();
    if(resultList != null && !resultList.isEmpty()){
        return resultList.get(0);
    }

}
```

saludos